# Proxychains is not going through any proxy

Tags: kali-linux, socks5-proxy, proxychains

I am using Kali Linux 2020.2 and I have configured `/etc/proxychains.conf` like this:

```
# proxychains.conf  VER 3.1
#
#        HTTP, SOCKS4, SOCKS5 tunneling proxifier with DNS.
#   

# The option below identifies how the ProxyList is treated.
# only one option should be uncommented at time,
# otherwise the last appearing option will be accepted
#
dynamic_chain
#
# Dynamic - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# at least one proxy must be online to play in chain
# (dead proxies are skipped)
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
#strict_chain
#
# Strict - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# all proxies must be online to play in chain
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
#random_chain
#
# Random - Each connection will be done via random proxy
# (or proxy chain, see  chain_len) from the list.
# this option is good to test your IDS :)

# Make sense only if random_chain
#chain_len = 2

# Quiet mode (no output from library)
#quiet_mode

# Proxy DNS requests - no leak for DNS data
proxy_dns 

# Some timeouts in milliseconds
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000

# ProxyList format
#       type  host  port [user pass]
#       (values separated by 'tab' or 'blank')
#
#
#        Examples:
#
#               socks5  192.168.67.78   1080    lamer   secret
#       http    192.168.89.3    8080    justu   hidden
#       socks4  192.168.1.49    1080
#           http    192.168.39.93   8080    
#       
#
#       proxy types: http, socks4, socks5
#        ( auth types supported: "basic"-http  "user/pass"-socks )
#
[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...
# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
socks5  127.0.0.1   9050
socks4  127.0.0.1   9050
```

I also had Tor installed and running while using proxychains. Here is the output of `tor status`:

```
root@kali:~# service tor status
● tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tor.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Sat 2020-06-13 19:33:10 UTC; 3s ago
    Process: 13092 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 13092 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 13 19:33:10 kali systemd[1]: Stopped Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master).
Jun 13 19:33:10 kali systemd[1]: Stopping Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)...
Jun 13 19:33:10 kali systemd[1]: Starting Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)...
Jun 13 19:33:10 kali systemd[1]: Finished Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master).
```

However, if I type `proxychains firefox www.whatismyip.com`, I still get the same IP address again and this is the output of the command:

```
root@kali:~# proxychains firefox www.whatismyip.com
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
root@kali:~#
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your config seems reasonable enough. Are you sure it isn't firefox exiting? Try `proxychains curl www.whatismyip.com`. Also try changing the url to `https://www.whatismyip.com`, the non-https version seems to have no output.

Comment: I don't know what was the problem there but after restarting 2 to 3 times it was working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me a simple restart after editing `/etc/proxychains.conf` worked.

Comment: You shouldn't have to restart the whole system, just a particular service (or two)

Answer (score -2):

try from an account other than root account. It worked for me

Comment: Any chance you would be able to say something about what the issue was and how your solution actually solved the problem?